# Need help installing Anaconda and Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

so i'm having some bad issues with my conda installation. I'm running this on MacOS Monterey 12.4

I installed the latest version "Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-x86_64.sh"
I then installed an env for spyder.

```
conda create -n spyder spyder
```

Everything seems to go ok, however everytime I attempt to run my code I get a spyder internal problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/person.blank/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtconsole/base_frontend_mixin.py", line 138, in _dispatch
    handler(msg)
  File "/Users/person.blank/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/widgets/debugging.py", line 278, in _handle_input_request
    return super(DebuggingWidget, self)._handle_input_request(msg)
  File "/Users/person.blank/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtconsole/frontend_widget.py", line 512, in _handle_input_request
    self._readline(msg['content']['prompt'], callback=callback, password=msg['content']['password'])
  File "/Users/person.blank/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtconsole/console_widget.py", line 2422, in _readline
    self._show_prompt(prompt, newline=False, separator=False)
TypeError: _show_prompt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'separator'
```

After this I removed and recreated the spyder env with:-

```
conda create -n spyder -c conda-forge spyder
```

When I attempt to launch spyder it never connects to the kernel in IPython Console.
So at this point I tried doing another:

```
conda update --all
```

This updates the files, but when I launch spyder again I get a missing dependencies.

## Mandatory:

qtpy >=2.1.0 : 2.0.1 (NOK)

Should it be this difficult to get anaconda and spyder working?
I've always had it working without issue in the past.
Anyway any help in solving this would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Reactivate the new env with `conda activate spyder-cf` and try to launch spyder? This was a known issue a while ago with regards to the not being updated to the most recent version or something IIRC

Comment: Have you tried to install the required version of the missing dependency from conda-forge? `conda install -c conda-forge qtpy=2.1.0`

Comment: More info on the original error message: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17627

Comment: Hey @NorwegianSalmon what do you mean by "conda activate spyder-cf", I will only be able to do a conda activate spyder as there is no spyder-cf env.

Comment: @mad yes I tried to install the required qtpy version, but when I run spyder it never connects to the kernel

Comment: I've also tried creating a new env called spyder with python=3.9 but I still get the same errors.

Comment: I think the connecting to the kernel error is related with this: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18174 It's caused due to some changes introduced in jupyter_client>=7.3.2. To workaround that install jupyter_client=7.3.1 from conda-forge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after research this extensively I thought I would provide the solution that ultimately worked.

To resolve this issue you need to create an env from the conda-forge repo, in order to get the compatible versions of spyder and the spyder kernels.

```
conda create -n spyder-cf -c conda-forge spyder jupyter_client=7.3.1
```

So just breaking this down for completeness:-

Creates an env with the name spyder-cf

```
create -n spyder-cf
```

Use the conda-forge repo

```
-c conda-forge
```

Install spyder and the jupyter client from conda-forge

```
spyder jupyter_client=7.3.1
```

Once done you can activate the spyder-cf env and run spyder. However if you wish to use alternative env's then simply create the env you like and open it from spyder. For example, if I want a python 3.10 env I would do the following:

```
conda create -n env310 -c conda-forge python=3.10 spyder-kernels
```

It's important to install this from conda-forge so that you get the correct spyder kernel headers.

Change to the spyder-cf env

```
activate spyder-cf
```

Activate your python 3.10 env

```
spyder activate env310
```

Comment: Where are the installation steps to install Anaconda or spider, any links which can help to install those two software.

Comment: Just download anaconda from the anaconda website and follow the install instructions. After that everything else is described above.